# Minimize Windows 8 Store App while tracking location with GPS

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, modern-ui

I'm working on a metro app and am having trouble finding how not to show the application.

We recently deployed tablets to our field reps, and need to add gps tracking.  GPS is much easier to deal with in the metro libs (it's like 4 lines of code vs. unmanaged) so we're hoping to be able to push a metro app instead of spending time coding a winforms/wpf desktop app (the tablets are full version windows, so it's an option if we can't hide a metro app.  I feel like it should be possible though as the start screen tiles update automatically without opening the main program).

In WPF, it's fairly simple to make a window invisible.  I'm creating the metro app in wpf, but it uses different libs than desktop and I may just not know how to do it.

In desktop programs, it's fairly simple.  You do something along the lines of:

```
<Page
x:Class = xxxxxxxx
..
Visibility="Hidden">
```

Unfortunately, with metro, the only options I have are collapsed and visible.  Collapsed doesn't seem to have any effect, unless it's just because it's not deployed and visual studio shows it anyway...

So basically I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to start the program minimized or hidden so that it doesn't interrupt the field reps every time it takes their location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to make a metro app and want it to run "minimised" you will need to look at [background task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj991805.aspx). To start the background task the user would still need to start the app at least once, futhermore background task have limitation how how often and how long they can run. Also there is a lot of constraint on deploying a windows store app if you cannot publish it in the store.

If your goal is to just have access to GPS through C# apis, the GPS is actually one of the  winRT api you can use from the desktop, you can find a tutorial on how to access winRT api from the desktop [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the complete list of winRT api accessible from the desktop (You can find Geoposition class among them).

Comment: Thanks Benoit.  I initially tried doing it as a desktop app.  I opened the manifest file and added the "<TargetPlatform>8.0</TargetPlatform> and imported windows.  I ran into an issue with typed delegates though.  When I ran the program, I received an error similar to "this option isn't available in the language" (I believe with typedeventhandler).  I haven't looked at the tutorial yet, I'll do that now, it may have a different means of exposing the RT api's than just changing the TargetPlatform.

Comment: I believe it does address that issue!  Thanks again!!  From the tutorial:

"You might need to add a reference to System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll as well if you are using mapped types like Windows Runtime event handlers:"

:)

Comment: Worked flawlessly!!  I was missing the System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll reference.  Added that and no further changes required.  Marked as answer and upvoted.  If I could do more for you I would :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into creating a background task that transmits GPS?  The background task can run without the app running.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain you can voluntarily minimize a Windows Store App on a user's behalf. I see nothing in IntelliSense about it, nor have I found anything online or see any app do it.

However, be aware that deploying the app without using the Windows Store -- sideloading -- requires Windows 8 Enterprise edition computers joined to the domain OR Windows 8 Pro with a sideloading key ($30 per key, purchased in packs of at least 100.) Perhaps a WPF app with unmanaged code is worth the money and effort.

Comment: We were able to get it in a desktop app with targetplatformversion 8.0 and a reference to System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll in the framework 4.5 folder.  We already use Enterprise, so that's not an issue :)  I started testing today.  It seems like it only updates every 5-6 minutes even if you set the Geolocator to update quicker (1 sec, 15 secs, etc), so I might look into that later.  As of now the lat/long are identical for quite some time (I had ~30 entries exactly the same before it updated.. but I also wasn't moving the tablet). I'd expect the last 2-3 digits to change frequently though.